# Is there a way of finding the general solution to this equation

Tags: trigonometry

I only know how to solve an equation $\sqrt{x}=\sin(3x)$ by newton raphson method of estimating the zeros of the equation. But I am looking for some other  method of generalized solution to such an equation.
Anyone to help me find the perfect way of finding the general solution. Thank in advance.

Comment: what is a method of generalized solution? thanks.

Comment: He probably means a method to find an algebraic expression of the solution(s)... And he'll probably be disapointed

Comment: Equations which mix algebraic and trigonometric functions do not show closed form solutions and numerical methods should be used such as Newton, Halley, Householder.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation only has three real solutions

$$\sqrt{x}=\sin(3 \cdot x)$$

$x=0$ is clearly one solution. You don't seem to be interested in iteration so that's all you can have...

Comment: Wanted the general solution

Comment: @DOCTOR you can't. We've already mentioned that, we can give approximations though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the numerical equivalent of $\sin(3x)$ which can be obtained by using the triple angle formula together with the identity : 
$\sin(x)= x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\dfrac{x^5}{5!}\cdots$

After simplifying the solution to the square of this infinite equation and applying the *triple angle formula* , we can generally solve for x using aquadratic or diophantine equation

Comment: What do you mean by *generally* ? Is this an approximate or an exact method?

Comment: We can show that the series converges as x approaches positive infinity, and the value of sin using this formula can be computed albeit quite tediously (Although I have seen computers run this formula with high precision). So technically it is an approximate method.

Comment: @G.sassatelli, I wanted the general solution that would depend on real number n